# Membership prices typo in the terms of service - Careers

Tags: support, status-completed, jobs

The [terms of service](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/terms-of-service) states:

> *...Until November 9, **2009** the Membership fee will be $29, and will allow your CV to be searched for 3 years from the date your Fee is paid. After November 9, **2010** the Membership fee will be $99...*

### 2010?

What would be the price from 10-nov-09 to 09-nov-10 then?

Am I to agree on the terms as they are, or should I wait for the amendment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

typo, should read 2009, will fix.

Answer (score 2):

From what I heard in the podcast I believe this is a typo and should be 2009.